# Circles created using pygame not showing up

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use pygame to make a few balls (circles). The code runs but the circles do not show up. I'm wondering if there is an error somewhere in the ball class or it's in the game function class.

This is the code for the balls class:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

import random

class Ball(Sprite):

def __init__(self, bg_settings, screen, user):
    super(Ball,self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.bg_settings = bg_settings
    self.image = pygame.Surface((bg_settings.ball_radius*2,bg_settings.ball_radius*2))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    

    self.velocityx = random.randint(-1 * bg_settings.ball_speed, bg_settings.ball_speed)
    self.velocityy= random.randint(-1 * bg_settings.ball_speed, bg_settings.ball_speed)
    
    self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0,bg_settings.screen_width)
    self.rect.centery = random.randint(0,bg_settings.screen_height)

    while (self.rect.centerx in range(user.rect.left - 30, user.rect.right + 30) and 
    self.rect.centery in range(0, user.rect.top + 30)):
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0,bg_settings.screen_width)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(0,bg_settings.screen_height)

    self.speed = bg_settings.ball_speed
    self.color = bg_settings.ball_color
    self.radius = bg_settings.ball_radius

def draw_ball(self):
    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.rect.centerx,self.rect.centery), self.radius)

def update_ball(self):
    if not (self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right or self.rect.left == self.screen_rect.left):
        self.rect.centerx += self.velocityx
    if not (self.rect.top == self.screen_rect.top or self.rect.bottom == self.screen_rect.bottom):
        self.rect.centery += self.velocityy
```

Here is relevant code for games functions class (I think just the update screen and creating the balls parts ??):

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, user, balls, gem):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    user.blitme()

    for ball in balls.sprites():
        ball.draw_ball()
    gem.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()

def set_balls(balls, bg_settings, screen, user):

    for ball_number in range(bg_settings.num_balls):
        new_ball = Ball(bg_settings, screen, user)
        balls.add(new_ball)

def update_balls(balls, bg_settings):
    balls.update()

    for ball in balls.copy():
        if ball.rect.left == 0 or ball.rect.right == bg_settings.screen_width:
            ball.velocityx = ball.velocityx * -1
        elif ball.rect.top == 0 or ball.rect.bottom == bg_settings.screen_height:
        ball.velocityy = ball.velocityy * -1
```

Main loop:

```
while True:

    gf.check_events(user)
    gf.update_user(user)
    gf.update_screen(bg_settings, screen, user, balls, gem)
    gf.update_balls(balls, bg_settings)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: where is the main loop of your game? and why do you have set_balls twice in here, is this on purpose?

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you are updating the balls position? You may not be using Pygames Clock, which is needed to create the small wait between updates. Without this you cannot view the ball.

Comment: @Rabinzel hi sorry i accidentally pasted the wrong part. I added the main loop now

Comment: From what I see at the code I can't find any obvious mistake why it doesn't work, can't run it neither because I guess there is still a lot more code you didn't post? did you try to add some print statements here and there to see whether your functions are executed correctly? for example create only one ball and print its coordinates. Also pygame Clock is a good idea like already suggested to slow down everything

Answer (score 2):

You must use `pygame.display.update()` at the end of your main event loop to update your screen. After doing this, the window would be updated to reflect the latest state and the circles would appear.

Comment: Hi, I tried that line in both the loop (which I now added onto the post) and in the update_screen function but neither work

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, you may want to use `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()` as I heard that it sometimes has problems with edited zone borders.
The main difference between these two functions is that `pygame.display.flip()` changes the whole screen while `pygame.display.update()` only changes parts that it detects changed, so that's why it may have problems

Comment: Hello, I have that line in my update screen function but it doesn't seem to work